# VBA runs on Windows Excel but not in Mac Excel

Tags: macos, vba, excel

when I run a VBA on windows excel, it works. When I run the same vba on excel for Mac, it doesn't work. Then I click "debug" it highlits the following part of the macro

```
Selection.Replace What:="-", replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: What's your selection? What's the error on Mac? Which version of Excel, 2011 or 2016?

Comment: None selection. I just stand in A1 to run the macro. Error is Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. Excel 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe `SearchFormat` parameter is not available on Excel for Mac:

You can remove `SearchFormat` and `ReplaceFormat` if they're not necessary, otherwise if they are necessary then use [compiler directive such as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264614.aspx):

```
#IF MAC THEN
    Selection.Replace What:="-", replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
#ELSE
    Selection.Replace What:="-", replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
#END IF
```

This will still use the `SearchFormat` and `ReplaceFormat` on Windows OS (but not on Mac OS -- in that case you'd need to use some additional logic) and it will not raise a runtime error on the Mac OS.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for this part of VBA. Anyway the macro is much more complex and there are more errors. I hit this now: ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Data!R1C1:R65536C32", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="Product_Solds", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion10